# Cloud Functions for Firebase: Headers Error When Trying To Read From Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this weird error when trying to access the firebase real-time database from cloud functions, and I cannot come up with any more ideas on how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createNewGame = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

        return admin.database().ref().once('value').then(function (data) {
                console.log("BLA");
                response.end();
        });
});
```

And the error:

```
info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Execution took 60010 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
info: Execution took 60046 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
error: Something went wrong with the function!
error:  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:504:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:511:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Thugm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:730:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Thugm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Thugm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:256:15)
    at ProxyServer.Supervisor._proxy.on (C:\Users\Thugm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\src\supervisor\supervisor.js:104:14)
    at ProxyServer.emit (C:\Users\Thugm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\eventemitter3\index.js:144:27)
    at ClientRequest.proxyError (C:\Users\Thugm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\passes\web-incoming.js:156:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
```

If anyone can even point me in the right direction at finding a solution, it will be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With HTTP functions, you don't return a promise like you do with other types of functions.  HTTP functions are terminated when you fully send a response to the client.

Try using something like `response.send("")` to finish your function with an empty response after the data is read:

```
exports.createNewGame = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin.database().ref().once('value').then(function (data) {
        console.log("BLA");
        response.send("");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, the same problem persists. The exact same error message is returned

Comment: I just deployed that exact function code, and I'm not having any problems.

Comment: Interesting, maybe it's the fact that I'm simulating the function locally on my computer to test? I will try actually deploying it to Google's server and see if that makes a difference. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: @SaimirSulaj same problem. I am testing my functions locally and it crashing everytime. I've tried several ways to terminate my functions. Nothing helps

Comment: If your function works fine when deployed, but has problems with local emulation, file a bug with all the details.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Deploying the function to the Firebase server solved the problem! Thanks everyone